Flutter animator optimization
So, what i want to achieve it one AnimationController with multiple animation, and i want to reverse specific animation in that controller, right now i am using multiple controller each as parent of single animation
Code :
late final AnimationController controllerHeightCard,
    controllerHeightNativeView, controllerInsertingView;

void heightAnimation1() {
  controllerHeightCard = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250), vsync: this);

  controllerInsertingView = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250), vsync: this);
  heightAnimation_1 =
      Tween(begin: 310.0, end: 380.0).animate(controllerHeightCard);
  heightAnimation_1.addListener(() {
    cardHeight.value = heightAnimation_1.value;
  });
  heightAnimation_2 =
      Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 75.0).animate(controllerHeightNativeView);

  heightAnimation_2.addListener(() {
    containerHeight.value = heightAnimation_2.value;
  });
  controllerHeightCard.addListener(() {
    if (controllerHeightCard.isCompleted && isSignUp.value) {
      controllerHeightNativeView.forward();
    }
  });

  controllerHeightNativeView.addStatusListener((status) {
    if (controllerHeightNativeView.isDismissed && isSignUp.value == false) {
      controllerHeightCard.reverse();
    }
  });
}

heightAnimationForward() {
  isSignUp.value = !isSignUp.value;
  if (isSignUp.value == true) {
    controllerHeightCard.forward();
  }
  if (isSignUp.value == false) {
    controllerHeightNativeView.reverse(from: 0.1);
  }
}

how do i achieve that !!
PS : I am beginner in flutter, sorry for the trash code

A common practice for more manageable and less repetitive code is to use a single AnimationController with multiple Animation objects
Here how you can refactor your code:
class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourWidgetState createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;
  late final Animation<double> _cardHeightAnimation;
  late final Animation<double> _containerHeightAnimation;
  bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      vsync: this,
    );

    _cardHeightAnimation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 100.0, end: 200.0).animate(_controller)
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });

    _containerHeightAnimation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 50.0, end: 150.0).animate(_controller)
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void toggleAnimations() {
    if (isExpanded) {
      _controller.reverse();
    } else {
      _controller.forward();
    }
    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _cardHeightAnimation,
              builder: (_, __) => Container(
                height: _cardHeightAnimation.value,
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.blue,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                    "Height: ${_cardHeightAnimation.value.toStringAsFixed(2)}"),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _containerHeightAnimation,
              builder: (_, __) => Container(
                height: _containerHeightAnimation.value,
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.red,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                    "Container Height: ${_containerHeightAnimation.value.toStringAsFixed(2)}"),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: toggleAnimations,
              child: Text(isExpanded ? "Collapse" : "Expand"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thank you for the response !
Thing is i want to forward or reverse the animation one after another
As much as i know this code will animate both animation at same time

Can you provide me with additional details regarding the order of execution of the animations? Are you planning to trigger a new animation when the previous one is finished? Do you have a particular sequential order in mind for the sequence of these animations?

yes,
i am trying to achieve this !
link without dependency(pub)
